# Laravel Class 'Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http' not found

Tags: laravel, httpclient, guzzle, laravel-api

I'm using guzzlehttp/guzzle and when i implement API on my login it gives this error.
Please help me to resolve it.
Thanks.

```
$response = Http::post('https://starznets.com/api/login.php', [
        'dosubmit' => 1,
        'user' => $request->email,
        'password' => $request->password,
        ]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Http` got added in `Laravel` `7.x`, i would guess you are not on a new version.

Alternatively you should include the facade when you use it.

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to import Http:

`use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;`

Comment: Then your version of laravel might not have that facade, as mrhn said it is a new feature.